# How can I use filter for array of object in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I getting a json array like:

```
{"1":{"postid":1,"name":"akash","date":"28 Jul 2014"}
 ,"2":{"postid":2,"name":"rajat","date":"28 Jul 2014"}
 ,"3":{"postid":3,"name":"rahul","date":"28 Jul 2014"}}
```

I am trying to filter this array by using this code:-

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="queryfield" />
<div class="privacy_wrp data"
     ng-repeat="res in faqallhtml | filter:queryfield"
     id="{{res.postid}}">
<h4> {{res.name}}</h4>  
 <span class="date">{{res.date}}</span> </p>
```

But I am unable to filter the result. Nothing is happening when I am trying to filter by this code.

Comment: that data isn't an array and you can't filter an object. Convert to an array of objects

Comment: why not try native js [*filter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using _.values() function from underscore.js

http://jsfiddle.net/8MVLJ/981/

Controller:

```
$scope.faqallhtml = {
"1":{"postid":1,"name":"akash","date":"28 Jul 2014"},
"2":{"postid":2,"name":"rajat","date":"28 Jul 2014"},
"3":{"postid":3,"name":"rahul","date":"28 Jul 2014"}
};

$scope.faqallhtmlValues = _.values($scope.faqallhtml);
```

HTML:

```
ng-repeat="res in faqallhtmlValues | filter:queryfield"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. it worked for me. but I would like to ask one more thing that if the name is like "Akash kumar Gupta" and "Rajat Gupta" .Then if I write on search box like "Akash Gupta" then I want the  result like all possible result match, Then It should return both of the result set (Akash and Rajat). Cause I am newbie in angularJs so I have not enough idea in this.

Comment: Please rate article +1. What we did in our project, add one more property inside each array item and set all possible text search results: if item is "{"postid":1,"name":"akash","date":"28 Jul 2014", "fullName":"Akash kumar Gupta"}" add new property {'search': '1|28 Jul 2014|01.07.2014|akash|Akash|Akash kumar|Akash Gupta|kumar Gupta|Gupta kumar|and so on...'} whatever user might need to search, add there

Comment: I need a generic search, I cant write this because I have more than 1000 Records like this, so I cant write all possible searches in new properties.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="privacy_wrp data" ng-repeat="res in faqallhtml | filter:{'property':queryfield}" id="{{res.postid}}">
```

it work for me when using array of objects

Comment: will not get around the fact that filter can't be used on an object

Comment: @sumitjainjr as Charlietfl said you cant filter an object try to convert it to array

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the answer you need to get the values , no need to load extra library for this case . You can simply do it manually

```
<div class="privacy_wrp data" ng-repeat="res in searchFilter(faqallhtml)|filter:queryfield" id="{{res.postid}}">
```

where searchFilter turn it to an array :

```
$scope.searchFilter = function(items) {
    var data = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
      data.push(value)
    })
    return data;
};
```

[working code](http://plnkr.co/edit/oNaVpBgeZ935BlWZQbGS?p=preview)